# Bot Builder for Node.js vs Bot Connector Node.js for creating bot that provides button options

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, botframework

I'm confused as to when Bot Builder for Node.js should be used to create a Bot vs using Bot Connector Node.js, or how they are supposed to be used together.

Specifically, its unclear to me how to respond to a user with keyboard suggestions in Kik or lets say button options in Facebook. It appears like Bot Connector Node.js is an entirely different approach to receiving messages from a user and sending a response back as shown in the documentation here: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/libraries/node/#navtitle. Why is Bot Connector Node.js creating a completely separate server? With Bot Builder for Node.js aren't I already creating a server to send and receive messages?

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework SDK for Node.js is available via the NPM module [botbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder). Install the module into your project using `npm install --save botbuilder` and start building your bot.

You can view the source code for the Node SDK in the repository [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) in the `Node/core/src/` [directory here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/core/src).

You will also find some helpful example bots that demonstrate various features of Bot Framework in the repository [Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples).

For more information check out the [Getting Started Guide for Node SDK](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/#navtitle).